# UISearchBar without a common tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am following this example to set up a UISearchController in my project:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014683-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

In the example they programmatically set up one tableViewCell to use for both the main table view and the search result, while I have got the cells that I will be using already, in both the main's and the search result's tableviews.

If I use the Storyboard ID's in mainTableView and searchResultsTableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath, there is a crash: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SearchResultCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'.

Any help with this is very appreciated!

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use .xib..

Answer (score 1):

What i mean is create a .xib like this:

[image]

Configure the `UI` of your cell and Set identifier like: `tableID`

[image]

Set custom class `dTableViewCell` for the property (IBOutlet)

[image]

Then declare a property for the class:

```
@property (nonatomic) dTableViewCell *tableCell;
@property (nonatomic) dSearchTableViewCell *tableCell;
```

Then inside your `UITableViewDelegate` :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
{

    if (tableView == self.mainTableView)
    {
        static NSString *cellID = @"tableID";

        //dTableViewCell.xib for mainTableView ]> example...
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"dTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellID];

        self.tableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    else //searchTableView
    {
        static NSString *cellSearchID = @"searchTableID";

        //dSearchTableViewCell.xib for searchTable ]> example...
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"dSearchTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellSearchID];

        self.searchTableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    }

}
```

also check your `SearchResultCell` identifier in your storyboard, because the crash is telling you that `SearchResultCell` is not registered.. Hope i've help you.. Happy coding cheers..

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it but unfortunately it does not work with the way I have it set up. It is as in the Apple example but with storyboard. So I set cellForRowAtIndexPath in both main tableview and search tableview class. If I use the cell I have created for search in my search class, it is a crash like before. I can make it work following: https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController but then the problem is that the search bar persists when going to the detail view...